# Pass asynchronous websocket.send() to stdout/stderr wrapper class

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, async-await, python-asyncio

I have a class function which unbuffers stdout and stderr, like so:

```
class Unbuffered:
    def __init__(self, stream):
        self.stream = stream
    def write(self, data):
        data = data.strip()
        if data.startswith("INFO: "):
            data = data[6:]
        if '[' in data:
            progress = re.compile(r"\[(\d+)/(\d+)\]")
            data = progress.match(data)
            total = data.group(2)
            current = data.group(1)
            data = '{0}/{1}'.format(current, total)
        if data.startswith("ERROR: "):
            data = data[7:]
        self.stream.write(data + '\n')
        self.stream.flush()
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.stream, attr)
```

The output is from a function run in ProcessPoolExecutor when inbound from websocket arrives.

I want the output printed in console **as well as sent to my websocket client.** I tried asyncing Unbuffered and passing `websocket` instance to it but no luck.

---

UPDATE: The essentials of `run()` and my websocket `handler()` look something like this:

```
def run(url, path):
    logging.addLevelName(25, "INFO")
    fmt = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s: %(message)s')
    #----
    output.progress_stream = Unbuffered(sys.stderr)
    stream = Unbuffered(sys.stdout)
    #----
    level = logging.INFO
    hdlr = logging.StreamHandler(stream)
    hdlr.setFormatter(fmt)
    log.addHandler(hdlr)
    log.setLevel(level)
    get_media(url, opt)

async def handler(websocket, path):
    while True:
        inbound = json.loads(await websocket.recv())
        if inbound is None:
            break
        url = inbound['url']
        if 'path' in inbound:
            path = inbound['path'].rstrip(os.path.sep) + os.path.sep
        else:
            path = os.path.expanduser("~") + os.path.sep
        # blah more code
        while inbound != None:
            await asyncio.sleep(.001)
            await loop.run_in_executor(None, run, url, path)
```

`run()`, `handler()` and `Unbuffered` are separate from each other.

Comment: Some comments: instead of `data.strip()` it should be `data = data.strip()` and later try: `if data.startswith("INFO: "): data = data[6:]`. try using `re.match(r"\[([^\]]+)\]")` instead of `re.split()` etc.

Comment: Right, of course! Thanks, i'll edit this.

Comment: Does `run()` creates an `Unbuffered` instance? Can you paste the relavant part of `run()` and show how and where `Unbuffered` is used?

Comment: When using `run_in_executor()`, there is no need to use a `with ...` command.

Comment: `'progress' in locals()` is always False.

Comment: Yes, I've updated my question with more code. See the comments in `run()`

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting `get_media()` to use `asyncio` instead of running it in a different thread would be the best.  Otherwise, there are some options to communicate between a regular thread and coroutines, for example, using a socketpair:

```
import asyncio
import socket
import threading
import time

import random


# threads stuff
def producer(n, writer):
    for i in range(10):
        # print("sending", i)
        writer.send("message #{}.{}\n".format(n, i).encode())
        time.sleep(random.uniform(0.1, 1))


def go(writer):
    threads = [threading.Thread(target=producer, args=(i + 1, writer,))
               for i in range(5)]
    for t in threads:
        t.start()
    for t in threads:
        t.join()
    writer.send("bye\n".encode())


# asyncio coroutines
async def clock():
    for i in range(11):
        print("The time is", i)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def main(reader):
    buffer = ""
    while True:
        buffer += (await loop.sock_recv(reader, 10000)).decode()
        # print(len(buffer))
        while "\n" in buffer:
            msg, _nl, buffer = buffer.partition("\n")
            print("Got", msg)
            if msg == "bye":
                return


reader, writer = socket.socketpair()
reader.setblocking(False)
threading.Thread(target=go, args=(writer,)).start()
# time.sleep(1.5) # socket is buffering
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait([clock(), main(reader)]))
loop.close()
```

You can also try this 3rd-party thread+asyncio compatible queue: [janus](https://github.com/aio-libs/janus)